# Custom XML-Based Property Source Loader for Use With @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: xml, configuration, spring-boot

I am interested in creating one or more custom property source loaders and using those property sources with `@ConfigurationProperties` in my application.

For example, I would like to develop a property source loader capable of loading an XML file and converting it into a set of properties that can be injected into my `@Configuration` annotated classes.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations="classpath:config.xml")
public class MyConfig
{
    ...
}
```

Is any such XML-based property source loader publicly available? If not, then how would I go about making it available to my application once I have it implemented?

Thank you.

Comment: Theoretically that should work out of the box, as a properties file could be expressed in xml as well as plain properties format. If you want some custom format you would have to write your own `PropertySourceLoader` or an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to pre-load your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check YamlPropertySourceLoader how it is implemented. Once you implement it method

```
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader#getFileExtensions
```

will be called once you add something like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations="classpath:config.xml")
```

But watching implementation of YamlPropertySourceLoader it looks like you will have a lot of work to do, with paring etc.

You should check if yaml will be sufficient for you because it gives you possibility to make structured properties:

For example, the following YAML document:

```
environments:
    dev:
        url: http://dev.bar.com
        name: Developer Setup
    prod:
        url: http://foo.bar.com
        name: My Cool App
```

Would be transformed into these properties:

```
environments.dev.url=http://dev.bar.com
environments.dev.name=Developer Setup
environments.prod.url=http://foo.bar.com
environments.prod.name=My Cool App
```

YAML lists are represented as property keys with [index] dereferencers, for example this YAML:

```
my:
   servers:
       - dev.bar.com
       - foo.bar.com
```

Would be transformed into these properties:

```
my.servers[0]=dev.bar.com
my.servers[1]=foo.bar.com
```

Even if you have XML docs ready and that is reason you want to load them in configuration it looks much more simple to convert XML to YAML (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) and than using existing YamlPropertySourceLoader than to write your own PropertySourceLoader.